# Blowfish decryption with Buffer from NodeJS to PHP

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I've been trying for a few hours already to convert the following NodeJS snippet to PHP without any results.

```
var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('bf-cbc', key, new Buffer([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
chunk = cipher.update(chunk, 'binary', 'hex') + cipher.final();

console.log(chunk.toString())
```

**chunk** is binary data from a file

**key** is a Blowfish secret key

The code that I've been trying in PHP is this

```
$cipher = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($chunk), 'bf-cbc', $blowfishKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, hex2bin('0001020304050607'));
```

But the output is different whatever I try. Maybe someone here knows how to proceed further or maybe I've missed something.

Comment: Why are you not using padding in the NodeJS code?  Also, Blowfish is insecure and has been for awhile.  You shouldn't use it.  Have a look at the code examples [here](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I understand and appreciate your examples and advice, yet what I need is to convert the said code from NodeJS to PHP, I haven't created that encryption and I would not use it myself but that's what I need.

Comment: It's a padding issue.  You're using different padding.  Read the docs for openssl_decrypt.